# Does Nvidia DIGITS install CUDA toolkit automatically?

Tags: cuda, nvidia-digits

I installed DIGITS 4 on ubuntu 14.04, everything seems running well. I used to install CUDA first in my previous machines but I didn't do it this time since I thought DIGITS should get all things set.

But when I try to check the CUDA version with nvcc, it says no such a command. Looks like the CUDA toolkit was not there. Even I do found those library files exits in /usr/local/cuda-7.5

Now I'm confused and not certain what DIGITS installed. If I have to install some other stuff need to run with CUDA. Is it necessary to install the CUDA toolkit or not? Is the library good enough?

Comment: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/docs/UbuntuInstall.md

Comment: Depending on how you installed digits, which you haven't indicated, yes, it installs the CUDA toolkit  (for example with `sudo apt-get install digits`).  Most likely you have forgotten to set your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables, [which is a necessary part of a CUDA toolkit install](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions).

Comment: Thanks for help! I did use  'sudo apt-get install digits' and did not set those environment variables. But there is no /bin folder under /usr/local/cuda-7.5, which is pretty weird.

Comment: I reinstalled CUDA toolkit and set all the environment variables. It's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It will install the runtime libraries, but not the compiler. You don't need nvcc to run compiled CUDA code.